# Why it is happening? java

Tags: java

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class sayangeffort extends JFrame{

    public JFrame instruc;
    public JFrame start1;
    public JFrame start2;

    public JPanel sayang;
    public JPanel effort;
    public JPanel inspanel;
    public JPanel startp1;
    public JPanel startp2;

    public JLabel l1;
    public JLabel l2;
    public JLabel point;

    public JButton start;
    public JButton ins;
    public JButton exit;
    public JButton ins1;
    public JButton ins2;
    public JButton ins3;
    public JButton BackA[]=new JButton[13];

    PleaseGumana p=new PleaseGumana();
    public Timer time = new Timer(2000,p);
    public Timer time2=new Timer(2000,p);   

    public static int num1;
    public static int check[]=new int [12];
    public static int j=0,flag;
    public static int pick1,pick2;
    public static int verifyer1=0,verifyer2=0,counter=0, counter2=0,sample=0;
    public static int pointcount=100;


    Random r=new Random();
    Dimension Imagedim;


public sayangeffort(){

    setTitle("Operation X: Memorylord");
    setSize(500,120);
    buildPanel();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(sayang);
    add(effort, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);
    }

public void buildPanel(){
    sayang=new JPanel();
    l1=new JLabel("Operation X:");
    l2=new JLabel("                                Memorylord");
    l1.setFont(new Font("Algerian", 72,25));
    l2.setFont(new Font("Algerian", 72,25));
    effort=new JPanel();
    start=new JButton("Start");
    ins=new JButton("Instruction");
    exit=new JButton("Exit");
    sayang.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    effort.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    sayang.add(l1);
    sayang.add(l2);
    effort.add(start);
    effort.add(ins);
    effort.add(exit);

        exit.addActionListener(new MenuButton());
        start.addActionListener(new MenuButton());
        ins.addActionListener(new MenuButton());

    }

public void buildStart(){

    startp1=new JPanel();
    startp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
    startp2=new JPanel();
    point=new JLabel("Points:"+String.valueOf(pointcount));


    for(int i=1;i<13;i++){
    BackA[i]=new JButton("BACK");
    BackA[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    BackA[i].setPreferredSize(Imagedim);
    BackA[i].setFont(new Font("Bodoni MT Black", Font.PLAIN,24));
    BackA[i].addActionListener(new PleaseGumana());
    }

    for(int c=0;c<12;c++){

        do{
        flag=0;
        num1=r.nextInt(13);
        check[c]=num1;

        for(int i=0;i<12;i++){

        if(check[i]==num1)
            flag++;

            }

        }while(num1==0 || flag>1);
        startp1.add(BackA[num1]);
        }

    startp2.add(point);

    }

public class PleaseGumana implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

if(e.getSource()==BackA[1]){

    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[1].setText("12 x 5");
    BackA[1].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=1;

            if(pick1==7){
                BackA[1].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[7].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[1].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[7].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;
                counter2++;
                }
            else if(pick1!=7){
                time.start();

                }
        }

    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=1;
    }   
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[2]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[2].setText("45 / 15");
    BackA[2].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=2;

            if(pick1==8){
                BackA[2].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[8].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[2].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[8].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;   
                }
            else if(pick1!=8){
                time.start();

                }
        }

    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=2;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[3]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[3].setText("17 x 8");
    BackA[3].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=3;

            if(pick1==9){
                BackA[3].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[9].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[3].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[9].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;   
                }
            else if(pick1!=9){
                time.start();

                }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=3;
    }   
}


if(e.getSource()==BackA[4]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[4].setText("31 + 14");
    BackA[4].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=4;

            if(pick1==10){
                BackA[4].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[10].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[4].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[10].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;   
                }
            else if(pick1!=10){
                time.start();

                }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=4;
    }
}


if(e.getSource()==BackA[5]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[5].setText("121 - 37");
    BackA[5].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=5;
            if(pick1==11){
                BackA[5].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[11].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[5].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[11].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
                }
        else if(pick1!=11){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=5;
    }
}


if(e.getSource()==BackA[6]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[6].setText("72 x 2");
    BackA[6].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=6;
            if(pick1==12){
                BackA[6].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[12].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[6].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[12].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
                }
        else if(pick1!=12){
            time.start();
            }   
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=6;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[7]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[7].setText("60");
    BackA[7].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=7;
            if(pick1==1){
                BackA[1].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[7].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[1].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[7].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
                }
        else if(pick1!=1){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=7;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[8]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[8].setText("3");
    BackA[8].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=8;
            if(pick1==2){
                BackA[2].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[8].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[2].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[8].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
                }
        else if(pick1!=2){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=8;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[9]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[9].setText("136");
    BackA[9].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=9;
            if(pick1==3){
                BackA[3].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[9].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[3].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[9].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
                }
        else if(pick1!=3){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=9;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[10]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[10].setText("45");
    BackA[10].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=10;
            if(pick1==4){
                BackA[4].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[10].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[4].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[10].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
                }
        else if(pick1!=4){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=10;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[11]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[11].setText("84");
    BackA[11].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=11;
            if(pick1==5){
                BackA[5].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[11].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[5].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[11].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
            }
        else if(pick1!=5){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=11;
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==BackA[12]){
    if(verifyer1<2){
    BackA[12].setText("144");
    BackA[12].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
        if(verifyer1==1){
        verifyer1++;pick2=12;
            if(pick1==6){
                BackA[6].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[12].setEnabled(false);
                BackA[6].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                BackA[12].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                verifyer1=0;
                counter=1;counter2++;
            }
        else if(pick1!=6){
            time.start();
            }
        }
    if(verifyer1==0 && counter==0){
        verifyer1++;
        pick1=12;
    }
}




    if(counter==1){counter=0;}
    if(e.getSource()==time && verifyer1==2){
        pointcount--;
        BackA[pick1].setText("BACK");
        BackA[pick1].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        BackA[pick2].setText("BACK");
        BackA[pick2].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        verifyer1=0;
        counter=0;
        }

    point.setText("Points:"+String.valueOf(pointcount));


    if(counter2==6){
        start1.dispose();
        buildStart2();
        //setVisible(true);
        }
    /**if(e.getSource()==time2){


        }*/
}
}

public void buildStart2(){

        start2=new JFrame();
        start2.setTitle("Operation X: Memorylord");
        start2.setSize(600,600);
        start2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        start2.setResizable(false);
        start2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        start2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        start2.setVisible(true);

}

public class MenuButton implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

    if(e.getSource()==exit){
        System.exit(0);
            }
    if(e.getSource()==start){

        setVisible(false);

        start1=new JFrame();
        start1.setTitle("Operation X: Memorylord");
        start1.setSize(600,600);
        start1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        start1.setResizable(false);
        start1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        start1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        buildStart();
        start1.add(startp1);
        start1.add(startp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        start1.setVisible(true);
            }
    if(e.getSource()==ins){
        dispose();
        instruc=new JFrame();
        instruc.setTitle("Operation X: Memorylord");
        instruc.setSize(500,600);
        instruc.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        instruc.setResizable(false);
        instruc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        instruc.setVisible(true);
            }

}
}


public static void main(String args [])throws Exception{

    sayangeffort cc=new sayangeffort();

}
}
```

Here is my code for my game, It is not yet finish, it doesn't have instruction, but try to play and finish it, you'll see my problem, Frames keep on appearing non-stop, but I can't see whats wrong with my code

Comment: Please format your code to make it easy-readable.

Comment: That's what happens when you crete a new JFrame and make it visible: a new JFrame is constructed and made visible. Since that's what you're doing in your listeners, it shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: but it is non-stop? why is that? Normally it should appear once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `time` is a repeating Swing `Timer` which never stops

This means that while `counter2` is equal to `6`....

```
if (counter2 == 6) {
    start1.dispose();
    buildStart2();
    //setVisible(true);
}
```

It will create, yet, another frame...

I would suggest...

- Stopping the timer when you no longer need it...
- Not using multiple frames, see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) for more details...
- Not putting ALL you code into a single file and separating each individual view into a separate file, extending from `JPanel`
- Using `CardLayout` to manage the navigation between the views, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details
- Having a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Thanks! i stopped the timer and now it works properly! More power

Comment: Where should I use that cardLayout?

Comment: Remove all the frames, except the master frame.  When you want to change between views, use the `CardLayout` to decided which view to show